# Python socket server receiving duplicate data

Tags: python, sockets

I have a raspberry running a server that communicates with a server on my laptop. I've done this through simple socket connections on python.

Like so:

server

```
HOST = "192.168.0.115"
PORT = 5001
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
while conn:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print data
    if not data:
         break
conn.close()
```

client

```
__init__(self,addr,port,timeout):
   self.addr = addr
   self.port = port
   self.timeout = timeout
   self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   self.socket.connect((self.addr,self.port))

#in a different file the call to send is made, passes list object as a parameter

send(self,data):
    if self.socket:
        self.socket.send(str(data))
```

setting a print statement in the client code results in (x,y,z), which is the expected output. However, upon receiving the data on server it appears in a pattern:

```
(x,y,z)(x,y,z)
(x,y,z)
(x,y,z)
(x,y,z)(x,y,z)
...
```

Why is the data being received as duplicates? Is it a property of TCP? If so, how can I counter this to receive the data as one sent string as I had initially.

Comment: Its hard to tell from snippet of code from the client, can you put up any more of what you have so far?

Comment: Added additional client information

Comment: The message sent is (x,y,z) and the receiving side is shown above as having duplicate (x,y,z)

Comment: Kind of, a lot of irrelevant things to the question. The problem can be recreated with isolating the client/server code in its own snippet so that leads me to believe the problem exists in the actual transfer protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP sends data as a stream. You can write data to that stream, and you can receive data from that stream. The important thing is that while it *can* be the case that one send corresponds to one receive, that's not at all guaranteed to be the case. You can send a big chunk and receive it in a bunch of smaller chunks, or you can send a bunch of smaller chunks and receive a big chunk, or anything in-between. You're in the latter situation.

To solve this, you need to layer some sort of framing protocol on top of TCP. There's two primary ways you could do this:

1. Prefix each message with the length of the message and then read that many bytes.
2. Put a delimiter between each message.

For your purposes (sending plain text without newlines), the latter with a newline as a delimiter would probably be fine. You can probably figure out how to do that, but essentially, do this repeatedly:

1. Receive some data.
2. Append that data to a buffer.
3. Search for a newline and process the buffer up to that point. Repeat this step until there are no more newlines.

If all you're doing is printing, you can replace all that by just looping, receiving from the socket then writing to `stdout`.